# curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Connection timeout after 10004 ms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

[image]

I have a problem installing a Laravel project, any help please

Comment: disable ipv6 for you internet connection https://networking.grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=17573

Comment: check your DNS settings and disable IPv6. i alson recommend installing OpenSSL php ext and enabling TLS protection

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form. Also, how is this problem related to Laravel 5?

Answer (score 5):

Just Disable `IPv6` and apply `Open DNS` it's working fine.

Step#1: In order to disable IPv6 in Windows follow the bellow explanation:

```
1.Use the shortcut, Windows Key + X to open the Control Panel.
2.Open Network and Internet.
3.Open Network and Sharing Center.
4.Click Change Adapter Settings.
5.Right-click your connection and go to Properties.
6.(Finally) Uncheck the box next to Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) to disable it.
```

[image]

Step#2: And for Open DNS see this screenshot.
[image]

(Done) that's it.

for more information please visit this link: https://networking.grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=17573

Answer (score -1):

Enable TLS and remove and reinstall

```
composer config -g -- disable-tls true
composer global remove laravel/installer 
composer global require laravel/installer
```

and u r done!

Answer (score -1):

run
`composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

resource = [laracasts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKKsM.png)

---

if not worked, turn 'on' or 'off' VPN.

---

and if still the problem not resolved check this page and changing your DNS. it was me worked!

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9376#issuecomment-718921358

[image]

Comment: Please consider to stop duplicating your own answers on different, older questions. Instead keep a list of related questions / answers in your original answer. It will also cross-link then the related questions on site. You have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score -1):

If Fail Two Ways
1-
php -S localhost:8000
or to have css changes
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
this will work fine
2- Install Git Software and goto you folder right Click and (Git Bach Here )
Enter your command (php artisan serve ) will work

Comment: The given error message is not solvable by starting a PHP server. Please don't post answers that do not relate to the given problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

First, make sure you have [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) properly installed on your machine.
Then setup the project via composer on terminal

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app

cd example-app

php artisan serve
```

Then you should be good to go

Or you can use the Laravel Installer on terminal

```
composer global require laravel/installer

laravel new example-app

cd example-app

php artisan serve
```

Comment: The OP already uses `composer create-project`. Can you explain why calling it again should magically resolve the problem?

Comment: It is possible that running composer create-project again could potentially resolve the issue if there was an error during the initial installation process or if there has been an update to the package that is causing conflicts.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it